# Add column to DataGridView (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, addition

I would like to add a new column in my project, but a weird thing happened...

My code

```
adapter.fill(datatable)
dgv.datasource = datatable
dgv.columns.add("test","testHeader")
```

The column index of test column should be the last index.
However, I found the column index is 0 and the original 0th index turns to 1

I am not sure what happened. Is there any factor could cause this problem? 
property settings of datagridview is wrong?

Comment: By the way, the test column is still shown in the last column in datagridview

Comment: If I add another new datagridview in this Project and do the same thing, the result is in same situation.

Comment: If I copy this datagridview to another whole new Project, everything is good as usual. Thus, I think there should be something wrong in the original project

Comment: Please try to edit the question. Move your comments to the  question body and try to add a bit more details (at least relevant part of an aspx markup). Othrewise this question will be probably closed.

Comment: The posted code does not duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code For Adding the Column

```
   Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    col.DataPropertyName = "PropertyName"
    col.HeaderText = "SomeText"
    col.Name = "colWhateverName"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple , get the total column count first and then add the column at the end :

```
  Dim col as New DataGridViewColumn
  col.HeaderText = "abc"

  dgv.Columns.Insert(dgv.ColumnCount, col)
```

If the above code doesn't help , try adding column to the `IDataTable` itself :

```
 datatable.Columns.Add("Header text", GetType(System.String)).SetOrdinal(datatable.Columns.Count)
```

Comment: This is a zero based collection. The next index will be ColumnCount NOT ColumnCount +1

Comment: It still not works. At that moment I add new column, the index of new columns is fine. However, after the dgv is shown on the screen, the index of new column automatically be changed to 0

Comment: @F.C.Hsiao,recheck my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
adapter.fill(datatable)
dgv.datasource = datatable
dgv.columns.add("test","testHeader")
```

seems to be working properly. 
I guess you are re-filling the datagridview that's why the added column is in index 0.

try to add

```
dgv.DataSource = Nothing
```

you will notice that the added column "test","testHeader" will be in index 0.
setting again

```
dgv.datasource = datatable
```

will cause the added column to remain at index 0 while the datatable will be added to the succeeding columns.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `DataGridViewColumn.DisplayedIndex` property to control order of visible columns.

Keep in mind that DataGridView tracks theese values and update them for other columns in your grid. Chaning some of them to 0 will update all other columns to highter values.

Answer (score 0):

This works because we clone an existing column while you cannot append a column that does already exist in a table. this also has the benefit of cloning all the column settings applied to the existing columns.

Clone a existing column:

```
    Dim Newtestcolumn As DataGridViewColumn = Existingcolumn.Clone
```

Adjust header text:

```
    Newtestcolumn.HeaderText = "test"
```

Add column to datagridview:

```
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(test)
```

If you add columns that does not match the current drawing format you need to update the datagridview object by calling:

```
    DataGridView1.Update()
```

If you want to write to a specific column or you dont know the column name
you use this to return the amount of columns and then point to column 0 for cloning fx.

```
 Dim Index = DataGridView1.Columns.GetColumnCount(DataGridViewElementStates.None)
```

You specify the column index like this:

```
    DataGridView1.Columns.Item(index)
```

going back to the first line we would then write

```
    Dim Newtestcolumn As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns.Item(index).clone
```