# New added column to the DataTable doesn't show at correct index in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataTable set as the DataSource for a DataGridView. I add a column to the DataTable at a specific index like so;

```
DataSource.Columns.Add(columnName).SetOrdinal(index);
```

However, the UI shows the new column added to the end (i.e. all the way to the right). When breakpoint in and take a closer look I can see that both my DataTable and DataGridView items have the new column indexed at the correct location. This doesn't make sense to me as the DataGridView is what I am looking at in the UI.

I've tried doing both the following to refresh the DataSource but as I said, the when debugging I can see the DataGridView has the new column at the correct index. It is just not displaying AT this index.

```
DataGrid.Refresh();
DataGrid.Update();
```

**UPDATE**

Looks like the field that hasn't updated is DisplayIndex. Am I missing a step here or do I just need to manually update this index when added the column? I assumed the DataTable DataSource would cover the DisplayIndex also?

**UPDATE 2**

Seems hacky but this works. Still would be interested if there's a better way of doing this.

```
private void ensureOrdering()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgvData.Columns)
        {
            col.DisplayIndex = col.Index;
        }
    }
```

**MCVE**

Having a `DataGridView` and a `Button` on form, if you add some columns in `Load` event of the form and bind `DataGridView` to the table, then in `Click` event of the button insert another column, you will see the column will show at the end of the columns list:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("X");
    dt.Columns.Add("Y");
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("Z").SetOrdinal(0);
}
```

Comment: This recent post had the same issue: [Add column to DataGridView (VB.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49882487/719186).  But like that question, too, the posted code doesn't reproduce the problem for us.  Try recreating the issue in a new project with minimal code.

Comment: I can confirm the issue and added *MCVE* for those who need [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can set the `DataSource` to `null` and set it back to your data table:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

*Note:* When `DataGridView` receives `ListChange` event of the underlying `IBindingList` it checks if the change is because of an add, remove or change in property descriptors, then it calls some private methods regarding to change in metadata of the data source. If you like to read the source code, start [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewDataConnection.cs,475).

Comment: *Still would be interested if there's a better way of doing this.* ← Being better in this topic is a bit opinion based, but I believe what I shared is a better way :)